# Resource blocked due to MIME type in Spring MVC when DELETE endpoint added

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, http-delete, x-content-type-options

I'm developing a web app using Spring Boot v2.1.9.RELEASE and Thymeleaf. The app mixes server-side rendering (Spring MVC regular controllers) with rest controllers called through AJAX. The page works like a charm as long as `GET` and `POST` are the only HTTP methods I use. As soon as I add a - totally unrelated, yet unused - `DELETE` REST controller, CSS and JS resources stop being loaded and errors like the following are shown in browser console:

`The resource from “http://localhost:8080/css/demo.css” was blocked due to MIME type (“application/json”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff)`

If I remove the new controller, the page starts working again.

When I inspect the request with Network Monitor, I observe that:

- `X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff` header is always present in the response, which is consistent with [Spring Security documentation](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.x/reference/html/headers.html).
- if the `DELETE` endpoint is not there, a `GET /css/demo.css` request returns with a `HTTP 200` code as expected. Both `Accept` (request header) and `Content-Type` (response header) are marked as `text/css`.
- when I add the endpoint, the above request returns a `HTTP 405`. `Accept` header is `text/css` but `Content-Type` becomes `application/json`. Also, a new response header is added: `Allow: DELETE`.

My guess is that when Spring scans for controllers and a `DELETE` method is found, some extra configuration is automatically added, but I couldn't find any reference to confirm that. I would like to know why is this happening and how can I avoid this behaviour.

Since I'm developing local, my Spring Security config is pretty straightforward:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManagerConfigurer authConfigurer() {
        return new InMemoryAuthenticationManagerConfigurer();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        authConfigurer().configure(auth);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

The REST controller I'm adding does almost nothing:

```
@RestController
public class MotivosController {

    private final String CONTROLLER_PATH = "/rest/motivos/{id}";

    @RequestMapping(name=CONTROLLER_PATH, method=RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public void deleteMotivo(@PathVariable(name="id") String id) {
        logger.debug("Eliminando el motivo " + id);
    }

    // Other members I consider unrelated to the problem go here...
}
```

CSS and JS files are being loaded in a `template.html` file placed under `src/main/resources/templates` folder, as follows:

`<link type="text/css" href="/css/demo.css" rel="stylesheet" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was easier than I thought and I was totally wrong with my assumptions. I confused `@RequestMapping`'s `name` attribute with `value` attribute, and because of that any URL matches that method. Changing `name` for `value` made it work.